# How to do IntelliSense for snippets when some text is selected in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-snippets

I wrote my first snippet which would wrap the selected text in `if() { selected text }` block.

```
"if block - snippet": {
        "prefix": "if block - snippet",
        "body": [
            "if( $1 ) {",
            "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT",
            "}",
            "$0"
        ],
        "description": "if block - snippet"
    }
```

When I select the text and hit CTRL+SPACE it shows the intellisense but, when I start searching for my snippet "if block - snippet" instead of searching it clears-out the selected text and start writing the "if blo...." :P

---

One workaround is to have a dedicated keybinding to trigger snippets but I want it more implicit like in the intellisense suggestions itself. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Update: vscode now "remembers the `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT` even though it appears to disappear as you write your snippet prefix.  So your original snippet works as you expect.  No need to use `$CLIPBOARD`.

---

Previous answer:

It is if you copy the selection to the clipboard first so you can use:

```
    "if block - snippet": {
        "prefix": "if block - snippet",
        "body": [
                "if( $1 ) {",
                "$CLIPBOARD",
                "}",
                "$0"
        ],
        "description": "if block - snippet"
}
```

Comment: @quetzalcoatl is right. I'm not looking for clipboard based pasting.

Comment: and everyone's right, I totally mistook VS <> VCode, sorry about that!!

Comment: It is one extra step to copy  your text after you selected it, then the snippet works exactly as you want.  Let's see if there is another non-keybinding way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Once hitting CTRL+SPACE and intellisense shows, instead of searching the snippet by typing its name, use the UP/DOWN buttons to search it.

Answer (score 0):

On the `editor.action.showSnippets` key binding, you can also do a `when` clause of `editorHasSelection`, and then you can use `Ctrl+Space` for both functionalities. It's not the nice inline snippet Intellisense, but it's closer to what we want.